# LogonUserA not working on windows server 2016

Tags: vba, windows, active-directory, windows-server-2016

We have publicaly accesible computer which is runing SCADA visualisation Movicon. This computer is permanently running and same user is logged in. Multiple different operators with different acces levels from operator, to shift manager can use this computer with different rights (Managed by movicon itself)

Certain operations can be skipped but only when operator gives his credentials (user, password). For validation on test pc running windows 10 we used this function to validate against windows users, without problems.

```
Private Declare Function LogonUser Lib "Advapi32" Alias     "LogonUserA" _
(ByVal lpszUsername As String, ByVal lpszDomain As String, ByVal lpszPassword As String, _
ByVal dwLogonType As Long, ByVal dwLogonProvider As Long, phToken As Long) As Long
```

But after migrtion to windows server 2016 PC this code started throwing errors user or password not valid, even when both are correct. I guess it has something to do with users not having high enough acces rights ?

Is there anything specific that might be causing this problem or is there any workaround on this problem ?

VBA and AD isnt really my expertise so i would apreciate any help.

@HackSlash Sorry new to forum, forgot to add how it beeing called.

```
Dim bResult As Boolean
Dim user_3, password_3, strDomain As String
bResult = LogonUser(user_3, strDomain, password_3, 2, 0, 0)
```

I tried to change the input parameters according to documentation but othing has helped.

Also Windows user is logged in as admin, I am not sure if application has been tested in Run as admin i will check it tommorow.

Maybe my approach is completetely wrong ? I tried to look for other solutions Cereros, LDAP, but i had no luck finding what i need.

> It looks like you are discarding the token. If that's the case, why are you using this function at all?

My only use is I have to validate if user inputed login and password are found and valid credentials on AD. If yes i
I accept user inputed data (manual entry about material identification in case barcode reader doesnt work) and go on. If data user logon is invalid data gets discarded. I dont need the token for anything else.

Comment: Can you show us more code about how you are using this function?

Comment: Have you tried running as admin?

Comment: Right, but are you using the token it returns? Is that what your use case is?

Comment: It looks like you are discarding the token. If that's the case, why are you using this function at all?